# cURL PHP not working if CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER set true

Tags: php, curl

I try to extract the HTML of a site via cURL for PHP. Normally it works fine, but there are some website the response is empty. For example if I execute the following script for the URL alditalk.de:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.alditalk.de/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/4");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

In this case the variable `$data` is empty. The strange thing about that is if I change `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);` the website will be printed on the screen. The problem is, I need the content in a variable for further operations.

I tried it locally on WAMPP as well on my Hoster. I also tried to set some header information without success. There are also no errors. Are there any solutions?

Comment: agreed, it works fine, you sure its empty? [link](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HMJXD2)

Comment: Ingo Just, have you ever managed to figure out why this happened?

Comment: I have same problem. curl_exec return false, if the content inside iframe and CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER set to true. How to further processing the content if CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  set to false ?

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me. i think you are not enable the curl extension.

Since you're using XAMPP, uncomment the line

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

in `xampp\apache\bin\php.ini`, and then restart the Apache service.

NB: In newer XAMPP versions, PHP has moved to root xampp folder `xampp\php\php.ini`.

---

Steps in `WAMP SERVER`

The steps are as follows :

1. Close WAMP (if running)
2. Navigate to `WAMP\bin\php\(your version of php)\`
3. Edit `php.ini`
4. Search for curl, uncomment `extension=php_curl.dll`
5. Navigate to `WAMP\bin\Apache\(your version of apache)\bin\`
6. Edit `php.ini`
7. Search for curl, uncomment `extension=php_curl.dll`
8. Save both
9. Restart WAMP

Comment: Thank you! But curl extension is enabled and it works fine for other websites, as mentioned above. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me ..I think the curl extension is not enabled well ..Are you using xampp ??

```
Go to http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/
```

and download the curl version that is same as your php version..

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest XAMPP Version for Windows (v1.8.3, PHP 5.5.11, phpinfo(): cURL Infromation 7.36.0). I didn't change any configuration.
As I mentioned above, it works fine for other websites, but especially not for this one. The same situation on my webhost (using PHP 5.3.18)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but it offers a bit of a workaround: Could you consider using ob_start() and associated functions to capture the output that you *are* able to get?

The idea above is a hacky way to solve it, of course. Before falling back on ob_start(), I would suggest double-checking all variable names, ini settings, etc., since it's always possible that you're doing something like accidentally trying to access the contents of $daya rather than $data -- which is precisely the kind of typo I just spent 45 minutes on in my own script. Fixing my variable name fixed the the misbehavior that had originally led me to this question.

Hoping that helps somebody. Cheers!